# radare2 unable to run a binary file

Tags: disassembly, radare2

I've been trying to debug a binary file in radare2 but it throws me this error.

```
$ r2 -d bin                      
Killing child process 1688 due to an error
Killing child process 1689 due to an error
[w] Cannot open 'dbg://./bin' for writing.
```

So I ran it without the -d parameter but I'm unable to execute the program by `dc` as the error below is shown

```
[0x00000610]> dc
Cannot continue, run ood?
```

I tried running `ood` but following prompt is received

```
[0x00000610]> ood
Killing child process 1711 due to an error
Killing child process 1712 due to an error
r_core_file_reopen: Cannot reopen file: dbg:///home/kali/Downloads/bin  with perms 0x7, attempting to open read-only.
```

Is this the problem with the binary or am I doing something wrong? Some help is appreciated.

Comment: what is this `bin` file? did you set it as an executable `chmod +x  bin`?

Comment: No I didn't, I'm an absolute beginner so thanks for pointing that to me

Answer (score 1):

> So I ran it without the -d parameter but I'm unable to execute the program by dc as the error below is shown

```
[0x00000610]> dc
Cannot continue, run ood?
```

radare2 will NOT continue or run the target program's execution because without the `-d` option, it'll run the program in [**static** analysis mode](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3475/39244)(*Static analysis of a program is the analysis of the code without regard to its execution or input.*)

if you intend to do **dynamic** analysis, add the `-d` option, for your example, you could do this:

```
r2 -d ./bin
```

- But also make sure the target program's file path is accurate.
- If the binary is 32bit, consider checking if radare2 is installed

  with 32bit support.